# Randoms in one Array

Tags: sdk, lua, coronasdk

I have six variables, that these variables have different position on the screen, I wanna put different images in these variables, hence i have an Array with the images.

```
misImagenes = {[1] = "rec/ro.png",[2] ="rec/az.png",[3] ="rec/ros.png",[4] ="rec/ne.png",[5] ="rec/ve.png",[6] ="rec/am.png"}
```

I put the elements of this Array into another  Array into that have 2 different randoms, like this:

```
randoms = {[1] = misImagenes[math.random(1,6)],[2] = misImagenes[math.random(1,6)] }
```

So, I wanna put this randoms of random form, hence, i create an random of the randoms.

```
randomRan = randoms[math.random(1,2)]
```

I put the randomRan into the 6 variables, but the images of the variables are always equals.

```
uno = display.newImageRect(randomRan,340,280)
dos = display.newImageRect(randomRan,340,280)
tres = display.newImageRect(randomRan,340,280)
cuatro = display.newImageRect(randomRan,340,280)
cinco = display.newImageRect(randomRan,340,280)
seis = display.newImageRect(randomRan,340,280)
```

This variables have the randomRan, but the images are alway equals, i need that the images are differents, 2 differents images in random variables.

Thanks

Comment: "I put the randomRan into the 6 variables," What do you mean? Please show the code.

Comment: You don't need to name the numeric indices of an array-like table in Lua. `{'rec/ro.png', 'rec/az.png'}` and etc. work just fine.

Comment: Can you give an example of your expected output?

Comment: I put the random Ran into 6 variables that are display images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what you want to do is commonly called *shuffling* and *filtering* an array.

Once you assign `randoms[math.random(1,2)]` to the `randomRan` variable, it is going to stay the same no matter what. It isn't like `randomRan` is going to be random each time it's used. However, if it were a function call, like `randomRan()`, then that would be a different case, depending on what the function did. A variable, once assigned to, generally stays the same unless changed.

```
math.randomseed(os.time()) -- Make sure to seed the random number generator.

local function shuffle(t)
  local n = #t

  while n >= 2 do
    -- n is now the last pertinent index
    local k = math.random(n) -- 1 <= k <= n
    -- Quick swap
    t[n], t[k] = t[k], t[n]
    n = n - 1
  end

  return t
end

local misImagenes = {"rec/ro.png", "rec/az.png", "rec/ros.png", "rec/ne.png", "rec/ve.png", "rec/am.png"}
local randomImages = {}

-- Make a copy of misImagenes for randomImages.
for i, v in ipairs(misImagenes) do randomImages[i] = v end

-- Shuffle the new array. This will randomize the order of its contents.
shuffle(randomImages)

-- Since you want only two unique images for a total of six rectangles,
-- we'll have to duplicate and overwrite the other four, randomly.
for i = 1+2, 6 do
  randomImages[i] = randomImages[math.random(1, 2)]
end

-- Now to filter the array with newImageRect.
for i=1, #randomImages do
  randomImages[i] = display.newImageRect(randomImages[i], 340, 280)
end

-- randomImages now contains all of your randomized image rectangles.
```

The shuffle algorithm was borrowed from [here](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=9908) to show an example of how this could work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing

```
var1 = randomRan
var2 = randomRan
```

then var1 and var2 will have the same value - randomRan does not get recomputed each time its evaluated. YIf that is what you want, you can repeat the expression you used to initialize randomRan:

```
var1 = randoms[math.random(1,2)]
var2 = randoms[math.random(1,2)]
```

and if you want to avoid retyping that ocmplex expression, you can encapsulate it in a function:

```
--Return a random image
local function randomRan()
   return randoms[math.random(1,2)]
end

var1 = randomRan()
var2 = randomRan()
```

Comment: I can't do that, because i can't put a function into a variable that is display image.

Comment: Maybe not a function, but how about a function *call*? `display.newImageRect(randomRan(), 340, 280)`